# How to call function in ngTagsInput - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, tags

I was trying to create tag. When user try to type particular character based on the typed values from array I need to display typeahead dropdown based on typed values.

When I click the value from dropdown, I want to call a function.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/css/ng-tags-input.min.css"/>

<script src="http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/js/ng-tags-input.min.js"></script>

<tags-input ng-model="model.invoiceSelectedAccount" 
                placeholder="Add Account" 
                replace-spaces-with-dashes="false" add-from-autocomplete-only="true" class="form-row29" display-property="shortname" style="height: 50px;background-color: transparent;" ng-change="getRolesOfSelectedAccount(model.invoiceSelectedAccount)">
      <auto-complete source="invoiceSingleSelectionaccountlist"></auto-complete>
    </tags-input>    

var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.invoiceSingleSelectionaccountlist = [{"groupcode":"PROMNG","shortname":"HANDY BUDDY"},{"groupcode":"FMDEMO","shortname":"FMDEMO"},{"groupcode":"SRTEST","shortname":"SR Test"},{"groupcode":"HBDEMO","shortname":"Proang"},{"groupcode":"INFOST","shortname":"INFOSOFT"}];

});
```

I am able to list and form tag from selected value. But unable to call function when value is selected from dropdown list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add inbuilt `on-tag-added="onTagAdded($tag)"` method call  inside `<tags-input>` element

And , `key-property="groupcode"` for unique identification.

**HTML :**

```
<tags-input ng-model="model.invoiceSelectedAccount"  on-tag-added="onTagAdded($tag)"  key-property="groupcode" placeholder="Add Account"   replace-spaces-with-dashes="false" add-from-autocomplete-only="true" class="form-row29" display-property="shortname" style="height: 50px;background-color: transparent;" ng-change="getRolesOfSelectedAccount(model.invoiceSelectedAccount)">
  <auto-complete source="invoiceSingleSelectionaccountlist"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

**Controller :**

```
$scope.onTagAdded = function($tag) {
   alert(JSON.stringify($tag));
   //your logic 
   }
```

Check plunker here :  https://plnkr.co/edit/7VNFHu?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. Its working fine. I have one more value called "ALL". If user select "ALL". Then I need to clear all selected values and need to show only "ALL" tag and should not allow user to enter any value in the field.